# Why do some numbers show up in my favorite tags section?

Tags: support, tag-watching

I've added a handful of favorite tags and some inexplicable integer tags show up alongside the tags I entered. Although the screenshot below doesn't show it, sometimes an integer plus the name of a tag I've entered shows up, like "457-ruby." I delete these tags and then they show up again. See this screenshot:

[image: favorite tags appearing as numbers]

If I click on the number tags, I get to a blank page like so:
[image: blank number tag page]

UPDATE: I just reproduced this by adding a tag for C#, clicking on the new tag, and then reloading stackoverflow.com. See new screenshot:

[image: blank number tag page]

Comment: @Bill the Lizard, thanks for adding the screenshot. Didn't have enough rep points at the time to add it.

Comment: This is really weird. A couple of questions: a) What browser? b) do you have any extensions/user scripts/etc. installed? c) Did you add the C# tag by entering it into the text box, or by clicking the star in the tag popdown?

Comment: a) Chrome, latest version; b) keyboard navigation extension; c) i added it by entering it into the box. Also I should add that when I first add the tags, they appear fine. It's only when I click the tag, and then reload the page and/or come back later that they change like this, but I can't reproduce it consistently with these steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems likely that your keyboard navigation extension is to blame. When you make changes to your Favorite Tags, the list is persisted to the database by calling `.text()` on the `#interestingTags` page element and sending that string back to the server. If the extension is inserting content into this element, such as the index number of the tag links (noting the values and sequence in your screenshot; the tag links there should be somewhere between the 550-650th links on the page), this information will get inadvertently saved as well.

Since the list isn't refreshed from the server when you add tags originally, you don't notice the problem then - it's only on subsequent loads when you request the messed up tag list from the server that you see something's wrong.

It's very possible that this only happens in certain circumstances, depending on the behaviour of the extension. If you have an installation link, I'll check it out in more detail, but based on what you were seeing this seems like the most likely explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem. All my favorite tags were suddenly changed like this:
[image: favorite tags]

I'm not sure but I believe it happened when I deleted two tags from my favorite list, and then navigated to another page.

Browser is Chrome 10.0.648.151.
Extensions: [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom), [Delicious Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gclkcflnjahgejhappicbhcpllkpakej), [RSS Subscription extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd), [stackoverflowerizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gledhololmniapejefjfocffkhoamlll).

I normally don't use Firefox, but I may have used it briefly while checking out the new Firefox 4 release. I have the [Stack Overflow Tag Icon Adder](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/59074) userscript in there.

**update**: I incorrectly assumed that I had the same chrome extensions everywhere. But I checked and it turns out I have the [KeyboardNavigation](http://www.chromeextensions.org/appearance-functioning/keyboardnavigation/) extension on one PC. Given the way it works by adding numbers to links, this is probably the cause.

Comment: Are you using any extensions or user scripts?

Comment: @Nick: I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting bug.... what tags exactly do you have as favorites? Maybe they have no questions, thus showing the ID or something like this?

Anyway, related bug:

[image]

I think that Tag with no question should not allow subscription.. :)

Comment: You can see my favorite tags in the screenshot above (ruby, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, etc.)

Comment: @Jamie so only five favorite tags?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, yes only five.

Comment: @Jam that's weird.. I saw that I can add tags to my favorites even if they don't exist (e.g. typed 611 and clicked Add) but you say you didn't do such thing? What about Geoff answer?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, That's correct, I never added a number manually into the box. Weird indeed. Now that @Geoff removed the tags, I will monitor and see if they come back. I'll try to correlate it to some action on my part if I can.

Comment: I just reproduced this by adding a tag for C#, clicking on the new tag, and then reloading stackoverflow.com. See new screenshot above.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the numeric tags from your preferences just fine - can you give me repro steps to create these undesirable numeric tags?  Are you entering these tags by hand or using the tag dropdown and if so from which URL?

Comment: I can remove them too, that's not the issue. The issue is that they show up  unexpectedly. I am not doing anything to actively create them. I am not entering them by hand, nor using the dropdown.

Comment: I should also mention that in the past every time I removed them they would eventually show up again (albeit, with different numbers).